# Definition of an image with the word on it, basically explaining its' meaning

Tags: definition, image-identification, word-meaning

I remember there was a word for an image with the word on it, explaining itself.. 
I can't remember what it's called an it's really bugging me!

Something like: [image]
[image]

Comment: Possibly [logotype](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/logotype) or  [wordmark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wordmark).

Comment: @LMS Very close, but not the exact word I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I think the word you're looking for is **expressive typography**.

> <sup>(Disclaimer: Without any good reference, such as a Wikipedia page or a well-known respectable book, I'll risk answering this question. I have only things around the web. If anyone passing by knows a good reference, please drop me a comment. Thank you!)</sup>

---

To support my claim, I tried an image search for *expressive typography* on Google, and here are some top results:

[image]

You can find what people say about expressive typography by searching for it as well. For example, here is an excerpt from a web page in the results:

> #### What is expressive typography?
>
> Expressive typography is an art form where text is highly visual; actually, type becomes an image there.
>   Letters are not just abstract notions, carriers of meaning; they are also real, physical shapes. Paying attention to those shapes, and using them as a visual element in graphic design, is an essential part of the art of typography.
>   <sub>http://artnaos.net/eclass/Typography/ExpressiveType.html</sub>

Answer (score 0):

The word you are after is [REBUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rebus)

Comment: A rebus is more of a word puzzle, and doesn't always contain the word itself.